# Azure Search returns different results for same query

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have an azure search query that returns different result sets each time I run it. Its the same exact query and it looks like it returns a different top n each time. Total hit count is same always.

Anyone seen this? Any settings that I can tweak?

Thanks!

Binu

Comment: I read that if the result has the same score, then it can return result set in random order, so is there a way to get consistent results?

Comment: Hi Binu, what does your search url look like? Are you using any scoring profiles?

Comment: If all of your results have the same score, then you cannot control the order. However, you can order the results by a value other than the score, if that's viable in your scenario.

Comment: Eugene - yes, planning to do that. is there a way to sort by @search.score

Comment: results are sorted by score by default and currently there's no way to request that explicitly - did you mean sort by something else and break ties by score? If so, please vote for this UserVoice suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6328693-sort-results-by-rank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When most results have the same score, in order to get deterministic results, you can order by some other field. It's not currently possible to do secondary ordering by score (to break ties) - if you need that, please vote for [this UserVoice suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6328693-sort-results-by-rank). Thanks!